# Error mysql al ingresar datos mayoristas

Tags: mysql, python, datos

Hola tengo un error de codigo al ejecutar una compra mayorista en mi codigo python, pls ayudenme

**Error**

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'de venta, Productos,  Talle, Cantidad) VALUES ("200", "2000", "18/01/2021-22:5...' at line 1')

**Base de datos**

```
def registrar_venta(self, PrecioU, Productos, Talle, Cantidad):
        total = PrecioU*Cantidad
        sql = f'INSERT INTO ventas (PrecioU, Total, Fecha de venta, Productos, Talle, Cantidad) VALUES ("{0}", "{1}", "{2}", "{3}", "{4}", "{5}")'.format(PrecioU, total, self.horario, Productos, Talle, Cantidad)
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            self.cursor.commit()
            print("Se ha guardado la compra, Volviendo al menu")
            os.system("pause")
            os.system("clear")
            arranque()
        except Exception as e:
            raise
            os.system("pause")
            arranque()
```

**Programa**

```
PrecioU = int(input("Introduce precio unitario: "))
Producto = input("Introduce El nombre del producto: ")
Talle = input("Introduce el o los talles de la venta (Puedes incluir varios): ")
Cantidad = int(input("Introduce las unidades vendidas: "))
database.registrar_venta(PrecioU, Producto, Talle, Cantidad)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explicación

Tu problema está en que estás usando un [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) con `{}` (para indicar las posiciones a formatear posteriormente) y a la vez estás usando `format()`.

Deberías utilizar una de las dos aproximaciones pero no las dos a la vez. Simplificando tu código tenemos lo siguiente:

```
f'("{0}", "{1}")'.format(PrecioU, total)
```

Usar llaves dentro de f-strings indica al intérprete que debe evaluar durante la ejecución lo que está dentro de ellas, por lo tanto `{0}` se convierte en `0`, `{2 * 3}` en `15`, etc

También se pueden utilizar métodos y en esencia es similar a lo que realizamos con `format`.

Volviendo a tu ejemplo, el intérprete convierte la cadena en:

```
'("0", "1")'.format(PrecioU, total)
```

Por lo que `format` no tiene nada que formatear y la cadena se queda como:

```
'("0", "1")'
```

En este ejemplo habría que utilizar cualquiera de estas dos opciones:

```
'("{0}", "{1}")'.format(PrecioU, total)
f'("{PrecioU}", "{total}")'
```

### Solución

Elimina el indicador de `f-string` de tu código o pon la declaración de los valores dentro de la propia `f-string`:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO ventas (PrecioU, Total, Fecha de venta, Productos, Talle, Cantidad) VALUES ("{0}", "{1}", "{2}", "{3}", "{4}", "{5}")'.format(PrecioU, total, self.horario, Productos, Talle, Cantidad)

# o

sql = f'INSERT INTO ventas (PrecioU, Total, Fecha de venta, Productos, Talle, Cantidad) VALUES ("{PrecioU}", "{total}", "{self.horario}", "{Productos}", "{Talle}", "{Cantidad}")'
```